# Acrobat JavaScript batch processing

Tags: javascript, acrobat

have to perform this task:

1. search for keywords
2. remove all pages after page with keywords

I can do this with JavaScript in acrobat. But I have to do this for hundreds of PDF files. So pasting this Script in hundreds of documents does not seem the way. The doc reads, that it is possible to open other documents and perform tasks on them. So my idea would be, to create a pdf, that includes a script, which will loop all pdf files in a specific folder, searches and cuts them.

Never worked with acrobat in this way. So I don’t know if this could work and if it would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

No need to open pdfs with JavaScript. There is a built in batch processing in acrobat.